# how to split a single row in to multiple rows in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

i have values in a single row which is separated by some delimiter, it is a single in row in data base. but when retrieving the values i would like to get the values as multiple rows based on the delimiter exist in the row.

following is my query :

```
SELECT (
SELECT 
RTRIM(ISNULL(T1.[CIMtrek_Keywords],'')) AS '@CIMtrek_Keywords'
FROM 
(SELECT 
     NULLIF(CD.[CIMtrek_Keywords],'') CIMtrek_Keywords
     FROM CIMtrek_SystemTable_DatawareHouse CD WHERE  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(CD.[CIMtrek_KeyField])),'')))) != 0 and CIMtrek_KeyField='CER Type') AS T1 
FOR XML PATH('Record'), TYPE ) FOR XML PATH('CarrierCode_Destination'), TYPE
```

and the following is the result i get.

```
    <CarrierCode_Destination>
  <Record CIMtrek_Keywords="Bucket - Minor Project|Bucket - Major Project|Budget - Named Project|AddFund - Named Project|Already Approved|Admin" />
</CarrierCode_Destination>
```

but i want to the keywords to come as a multiple row in the above case it would be five rows, because later on i will have to bring these values in combo box.

Please help me to do this.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str) function. It returns a table of splitted values, based on input string and a delimeter.

Usage:

```
select * 
from dbo.fn_ParseText2Table('Bucket - Minor Project|Bucket - Major Project|Budget - Named Project|AddFund - Named Project|Already Approved|Admin','|')
```

Output:

```
POSITION    INT_VALUE   NUM_VALUE   TXT_VALUE
1           (null)      (null)      Bucket - Minor Project
2           (null)      (null)      Bucket - Major Project
3           (null)      (null)      Budget - Named Project
4           (null)      (null)      AddFund - Named Project
5           (null)      (null)      Already Approved
6           (null)      (null)      Admin
```

I've prepared SqlFiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9030

Comment: Please see my question, your answer is not helpful to me sorry and thanks for the effort

Comment: @Anto why *isn't* it helpful? What do you need?

Comment: usr Hope i have to create another table to store the value as per the above answer if i am not wrong also it involves another function to be returned.

Comment: @Anto you said **"i would like to get the values as multiple rows based on the delimiter exist in the row."** The function I described perfectly does that

Comment: @Anto you cannot expect the answer to do all your work. Answers are meant to address the core problem and enable you to finish the job yourself. You should mark this as accepted and actually try to use it!

Comment: @usr you can't force some one to mark as accepted it will be done if it meets the requirement. i have already up voted for Andrey Gordeev efforts.